# PHPMailer - Show success message after redirect

Tags: laravel-4

I building a very simple app with Laravel4 and so far i have managed to set up PHPMailer to work with a contact form, the users fill in their details and send me an email, normal stuff, everything works fine.
After the user sent the email successfully, he is redirected to the home page via

```
if($m->send()) {
    header('Location: /path/to/home/');
    die();
}
```

Now what i need is a success message that appears at the top of the homepage if the user has been redirected after a successfully sent email.

I have a div with `.success` class sitting on top of my home page, absolutely positioned out of view, with a negative Y value.
I tried pulling it down after on `$m->send()` like so:

```
    if($m->send()) {
        header('Location: /path/to/home/');
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
                $('.success').animate({
                   top: 0
                }, 2000);
              </script>";
        die();
    }
```

but it didnt work. In fact, nothing i echo after the header() has any effect.

What can I do?

Thank you guys!

Answer (score 0):

This is simple HTTP - when you set the `Location` header, it's telling the browser to leave the page you're on and go somewhere else - anything that happens afterwards (like that little JS snippet) will never reach the browser. You need to put that snippet on the page you're redirecting to, not on this one.

Comment: I realize now that nothing that goes after the header() is actually executed. So, im trying to set a `$_SESSION['success'] = true` before the header, and then on the homepage, if it is true, execute said script. But still no luck...

Comment: You may need to call `session_write_close();`, and make sure you have a session open.

Comment: I did open sessions, everything is working now. I didn't exactly find the perfect time to kill the sessions completely yet so for now Im simply unseting the data at the end of the pages where the session is open using for example 
`<?php
      unset($_SESSION['success']);
   ?>`

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem after realizing that you can't use jquery on the document before you actually link the jquery lib in.

So, in my phpmailer config file, I set `$_SESSION['success'] = true` before i redirect with the `header('Location: /path/to/home/');` , and then, on the Homepage, the page I wanted the success message to be displayed on, I added this bit of code (AFTER linking the jQuery library):

```
    <?php
        if(isset($_SESSION['success']) && $_SESSION['success'] == true ) {
    ?>
        <script type='text/javascript'> $('.success').animate({top : 0}, 'normal').delay(3000).animate({top : -57}, 'normal');</script>
    <?php
        } else {
            $_SESSION['success'] = false;
        }
    ?>
```

I don't know if this is a good practice but it does work.

I also had to `session_start();` on my Homepage (obviously).

Hope this helps anyone in the same situation!